# Unhandled Exception: Exception: Failed to create Register

Tags: flutter, dart

the method name is createResgister so this is the method that returns a Future that contains a Response. ok and in there is TextEdittingController of each form i want post and the api i want to post it too

ok am having an error trying to post a register form to an apiKey code:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:logistics_app/models/registerApi.dart';
import 'package:logistics_app/ui/dashboard_view.dart';
import 'package:logistics_app/utils/validation.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import '../ui/login_view.dart';



class UserOnboardingModel extends ChangeNotifier with ValidationMixin{

  TextEditingController firstController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController lastController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController phoneController = TextEditingController();
  bool showPassword = true;

  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  Future<RegisterModel> _futureRegister;

  Future<RegisterModel> createRegister()async{
    final http.Response response = await http.post(
        "apiKey",
        body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
          'firstName' : validateFirstName(firstController.text),
          'lastName' : validateLastName(lastController.text),
          'emailAddress' : validateEmail(emailController.text),
          'phoneNumber' : validatePhoneNumber(phoneController.text),
          'password' : validatePassword(passwordController.text)
        })
    );
    if(response.statusCode == 201){
      return RegisterModel.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    }else{
      throw Exception('Failed to create Register');
    }
  }

  void passRegister(){
    _futureRegister = createRegister();
  }

  void registerForm(){
    FutureBuilder<RegisterModel>(
      future: _futureRegister,
      builder: (context, snapshot){
        if(snapshot.hasData){
          return Column(
            children: [
              Text(snapshot.data.firstName),
              Text(snapshot.data.lastName),
              Text(snapshot.data.emailAddress),
              Text(snapshot.data.phoneNumber),
              Text(snapshot.data.password)
            ],
          );
        }else if(snapshot.hasError){
          return Text("${snapshot.error}");
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
  }

  void togglePassword(){
    showPassword = !showPassword;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void validateForm(){
    formKey.currentState.validate();
  }

  void moveToLogin(context){
    //go to login page
    if(formKey.currentState.validate()){
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, LogIn.LOG_IN_ROUTE);
    }
    else{
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: "Please Fill The Form",
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
          gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
        timeInSecForIosWeb: 5,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      );
    }
  }

  void moveToDashBoardView(context){
    //go to login page
    if(formKey.currentState.validate()){
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => DashboardView()
      ));
    }
    else{
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: "Please Fill The Form",
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
        gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
        timeInSecForIosWeb: 5,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      );
    }
  }

  void moveToSignup(){
    //go to sign up page
    notifyListeners();
  }
  void moveToForgottenPassword(){
    //go to forgotten password page
    notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

now this is the error am getting saying: `Failed to create Register`

```
E/flutter ( 7901): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: Exception: Failed to create Register
E/flutter ( 7901): #0      UserOnboardingModel.createRegister (package:logistics_app/models/userOnboardingModel.dart:42:7)
E/flutter ( 7901): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7901): #1      UserOnboardingModel.passRegister (package:logistics_app/models/userOnboardingModel.dart:47:23)
E/flutter ( 7901): #2      _buildCircleAvatar.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:logistics_app/ui/sign_up_view.dart:241:18)
E/flutter ( 7901): #3      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:992:19)
E/flutter ( 7901): #4      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1098:38)
E/flutter ( 7901): #5      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:184:24)
E/flutter ( 7901): #6      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:524:11)
E/flutter ( 7901): #7      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:284:5)
E/flutter ( 7901): #8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:256:7)
E/flutter ( 7901): #9      GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:158:27)
E/flutter ( 7901): #10     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:224:20)
E/flutter ( 7901): #11     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:200:22)
E/flutter ( 7901): #12     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:158:7)
E/flutter ( 7901): #13     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:104:7)
E/flutter ( 7901): #14     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:88:7)
E/flutter ( 7901): #15     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1206:13)
E/flutter ( 7901): #16     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter ( 7901): #17     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)
E/flutter ( 7901): #18     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:267:10)
E/flutter ( 7901): #19     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:176:5)
E/flutter ( 7901):
```

Comment: okay... now given that *you* throw this error *yourself* in your code, what exactly is your question?

Comment: is it meant to be the other way around?

Comment: something like this:  `if(response.statusCode == 201){
throw Exception('Failed to create Register');
      );
    }else{
return RegisterModel.fromJson(json.decode(response.body)
    }`

Comment: What do you mean "is it meant", this is **your code**, if *you* don't know what it is meant to be, we surely cannot help.

Comment: @nvoigt i want it to post the inputed form

Comment: @nvoigt i want it to post the inputed form

Comment: pla man help me out here am confuse pls thats y i brought the issue here so i can get help pls

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I'm not trying to be mean. You coded this. You *made it* throw that exception, so... what do you *want* it do instead?

Comment: @UchennaJustice, what he is trying to say is Your code throws the exception because the condition in the `if`  statement was not met. In your `else` part, you did `throw Exception(...);` which is exactly what is happening. If you are confused about making a http request. Refer to the official documentation here: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/send-data#2-sending-data-to-server

Comment: ok what am trying to do is i want it to be meant

Comment: Bcos one the test in postman it's return 400.... thats wat am getting in test ok the api